# Self-written Neural Network

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

I created the following Neural Network in Python. It uses weights and biases which should follow standard procedure.

```
# Define size of the layers, as well as the learning rate alpha and the max error
inputLayerSize = 2
hiddenLayerSize = 3
outputLayerSize = 1
alpha = 0.5
maxError = 0.001

# Import dependencies
import numpy
from sklearn import preprocessing

# Make random numbers predictable
numpy.random.seed(1)

# Define our activation function
# In this case, we use the Sigmoid function
def sigmoid(x):
    output = 1/(1+numpy.exp(-x))
    return output
def sigmoid_derivative(x):
    return x*(1-x)

# Define the cost function
def calculateError(Y, Y_predicted):
    totalError = 0
    for i in range(len(Y)):
        totalError = totalError + numpy.square(Y[i] - Y_predicted[i])
    return totalError

# Set inputs
# Each row is (x1, x2)
X = numpy.array([
            [7, 4.7],
            [6.3, 6],
            [6.9, 4.9],
            [6.4, 5.3],
            [5.8, 5.1],
            [5.5, 4],
            [7.1, 5.9],
            [6.3, 5.6],
            [6.4, 4.5],
            [7.7, 6.7]
            ])

# Normalize the inputs
#X = preprocessing.scale(X)

# Set goals
# Each row is (y1)
Y = numpy.array([
            [0],
            [1],
            [0],
            [1],
            [1],
            [0],
            [0],
            [1],
            [0],
            [1]
            ])

# Randomly initialize our weights with mean 0
weights_1 = 2*numpy.random.random((inputLayerSize, hiddenLayerSize)) - 1
weights_2 = 2*numpy.random.random((hiddenLayerSize, outputLayerSize)) - 1

# Randomly initialize our bias with mean 0
bias_1 = 2*numpy.random.random((hiddenLayerSize)) - 1
bias_2 = 2*numpy.random.random((outputLayerSize)) - 1

# Loop 10,000 times
for i in xrange(100000):

    # Feed forward through layers 0, 1, and 2
    layer_0 = X
    layer_1 = sigmoid(numpy.dot(layer_0, weights_1)+bias_1)
    layer_2 = sigmoid(numpy.dot(layer_1, weights_2)+bias_2)

    # Calculate the cost function
    # How much did we miss the target value?
    layer_2_error = layer_2 - Y

    # In what direction is the target value?
    # Were we really sure? if so, don't change too much.
    layer_2_delta = layer_2_error*sigmoid_derivative(layer_2)

    # How much did each layer_1 value contribute to the layer_2 error (according to the weights)?
    layer_1_error = layer_2_delta.dot(weights_2.T)

    # In what direction is the target layer_1?
    # Were we really sure? If so, don't change too much.
    layer_1_delta = layer_1_error * sigmoid_derivative(layer_1)

    # Update the weights
    weights_2 -= alpha * layer_1.T.dot(layer_2_delta)
    weights_1 -= alpha * layer_0.T.dot(layer_1_delta)

    # Update the bias    
    bias_2 -= alpha * numpy.sum(layer_2_delta, axis=0)
    bias_1 -= alpha * numpy.sum(layer_1_delta, axis=0)

    # Print the error to show that we are improving
    if (i% 1000) == 0:
        print "Error after "+str(i)+" iterations: " + str(calculateError(Y, layer_2))

    # Exit if the error is less than maxError
    if(calculateError(Y, layer_2)<maxError):
        print "Goal reached after "+str(i)+" iterations: " + str(calculateError(Y, layer_2)) + " is smaller than the goal of " + str(maxError)
        break

# Show results
print ""
print "Weights between Input Layer -> Hidden Layer"
print weights_1
print ""

print "Bias of Hidden Layer"
print bias_1
print ""

print "Weights between Hidden Layer -> Output Layer"
print weights_2
print ""

print "Bias of Output Layer"
print bias_2
print ""

print "Computed probabilities for SALE (rounded to 3 decimals)"
print numpy.around(layer_2, decimals=3)
print ""

print "Real probabilities for SALE"
print Y
print ""

print "Final Error"
print str(calculateError(Y, layer_2))
```

Using 32,000 epochs I manage to get on average a final error of 0.001.

However, compared to the `MLPClassifier` (Scikit-Learn package) using the same parameters:

```
mlp = MLPClassifier(
     hidden_layer_sizes=(3,),
     max_iter=32000,
     activation='logistic',
     tol=0.00001,
     verbose='true')
```

My result is pretty bad. The `MLPClassifier` gets a final error of 0 when I run it on the same data, after about 10,000 epochs. For both networks I use an input layer size of 2, hidden layer size of 3 and an output layer of 1.

Why does my network need that many more epochs to train? Am I missing an important part?

Comment: For one, you want to have one or zero bias nodes per layer, not a "bias parameter" for each node in a layer.

Comment: Are you sure? The way I've solved this is I don't really have a different bias for each node, but instead a different weight for each node bias. **Explanation:** Each node has a default bias of 1. However, each node has a different bias weight. Since _bias = bias * biasWeight_ we can ignore the "default bias of 1" and just use the bias weight directly. Or is this wrong?

Comment: I just tested it with using the same bias (an biasWeight) for the hidden layer and the output layer. Still bad results (final error of >0.5). You can try it for yourself by exchanging `bias_1 = 2*numpy.random.random((hiddenLayerSize)) - 1` with `bias_1 = numpy.array([1.0, 1.0, 1.0])`.

Note that the **scikit-learn** library uses a different bias weight for each node. If I try that (achieved by exchanging `bias_1 += alpha * numpy.mean(layer_1_delta)` with `bias_1 += alpha * numpy.mean(layer_1_delta, axis=0)`), I still get bad results.

Comment: I have edited my post and now it uses a different bias_weight for each node.

Comment: Why is the input data not normalized? (Don't know if related to the solution)

Comment: The data is "normalized" already - normalizing it again would make the solution trivial. I want to solve it without normalizing it further.

Comment: What do you mean by "Self-written"?

Answer (score 2):

1. You import your dependencies at the top of your file.

> Imports are always put at the top of the file, just after any module comments and docstrings, and before module globals and constants. - [PEP 8 Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)

2. `numpy.random.seed` doesn't really make random numbers predictable, it actually helps reproducing them.
3. You don't need to explicitly call `str` in your last `print` statement
4. According to [PEP 8 Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports), variable names better be lower case `separated_with_underscore`.
5. For better performance, scale your inputs between `-1` (or `0`) and `1`. I see you're commenting it off.

Now let's get to why your network needs more epochs to train:

- You update parameters (weights and biases) after doing the backward pass for a single sample. This is also known as **stochastic gradient descent** (1 epoch = 1 sample).
- The `MLPClassifier` from `sklearn` doesn't update parameters (weights and biases) after doing the backward pass for a single sample. Instead it computes the average of parameters updates over a mini-batch of examples. This is also know as **mini-batch gradient descent** (1 epoch = a mini-batch of samples). For relatively big datasets, by default, the `MLPClassifer` uses a batch of `200` example for each epoch. But in your case, it uses the whole dataset, because your dataset is smaller than `200`. When the whole dataset is used to compute the updates, we call it **gradient descent** (1 epoch = the whole dataset).
- A single epoch in the `sklearn` implementation takes into account your whole dataset, thus it makes a more accurate updates. In your case, it takes less epochs like this to reach the minimum error.

I suggest you read about the different basic learning algorithms for neural networks and try to implement them using `numpy`: gradient descent, stochastic gradient descent, and mini-batch gradient.